# HTML encoding TEL: and USSD String on Android devices

Tags: android, html, ussd, tel

I want to encode following USSD code in html **67*+111#

I'm trying <a href='tel:**67*%2B111%23'/>

But when i click it on android device it misses sign +
so i got in dialer **67*111# (without +) instead of **67*+111#

PS. On IOS <a href='tel:**67*%2B111%23'/>  works as expected.

BR
Roman

Answer (score 0):

First, you need call permission, for that modify the Manifest file as follows.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Call the following function and it will do as you expect it.

```
callUssd("*67*+111");
```

```
private void callUssd(String ussd){
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd + Uri.encode("#"))));
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i am curious how android works with HTML on third party site, not the android code itself

Comment: If I got you correctly you wanted to know how Android handles " **67*+111#" from a website using a WebView?

Comment: I tried the possible ways but it was unfruitful. Things to try change # to %23 or escape  #. I don't have access to a webserver at the moment so It might work for you.